# Calling a jQuery plugin inside itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, comet

I am trying to create a comet like thing. I have a plugin that collects data from a php page. The problem is that i dont know how to call the plugin inside itself.

If it were a function i could go like this: `function j () {setTimeout(j(), 1000);}`, but i am using a jQuery plugin.

Here is my plugin code:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.watch = function(ops) {
    var
        $this_ = this,
        setngs = $.extend({
            'type'  : 'JSON',
            'query' : 'GET',
            'url'   : '',
            'data'  : '',
            'wait'  : 1000
        }, ops);

        if (setngs.type === '') {
            return false;
        } else if (setngs.query === '') {
            return false;
        } else if (setngs.url === '') {
            return false;
        } else if (setngs.wait === '') {
            return false;
        } else if (setngs.wait === 0) {
            setngs.wait = 1000;
        }

        var xhr = $.ajax({
            type        : setngs.query,
            dataType    : setngs.type,
            url         : setngs.url,
            success     : function(data) {
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var html = $this_.html(), str = '<li class="post" id="post-' + data[i].id + '"><div class="inner"><div class="user">' + data[i].user + '</div><div class="body">' + data[i].body + '</div></div></li>';
                    $this_.html(str + html);
                }
                setTimeout($this_, 1000);
            }
        });
};
})(jQuery);
```

where it says `setTimeout($this_, 1000);` this is where im having trouble. I don't know what to call the plugin as. `$this_` is what I thought might work but I am wrong. That is what i need to replace.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here I would probably make use of JavaScript's `call()` to call a function. [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call).

Hence, within the plugin you could call it with `$.fn.watch.call(this)`. The argument passed into `call` sets the scope on it, so pass in `this` to call it within the same scope.

I put together a basic example of how this works on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oyuqes/edit#javascript,html).

You can use it within a `setTimeout` like so:

```
setTimeout(function() { $.fn.watch.call(this) }, 1000);
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/oyuqes/2/edit)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: how about var $this_ = $.fn.watch; ? closure over the completed function should allow the call... Not 100% but seems to make sense to me. +1 though for .call and discussion about this context